# How to calculate date in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example:

```
td = created_at
ta = updated_at

# is there a clean and nice way to print number of days and hours, minutes??
diff = ta - td
```

Comment: just plain ruby, or are you using rails? (based on the created_at/updated_at). If Rails look at distance_of_time_in_words (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [distance_of_time_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words), it will not always give you the exact days and hours but often its result is more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the pure Ruby you can use [this](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2109) snippet:

```
require 'date'

class Date
  def distance_to(end_date)
    years = end_date.year - year
    months = end_date.month - month
    days = end_date.day - day
    if days < 0
      days += 30
      months -= 1
    end
    if months < 0
      months += 12
      years -= 1
    end
    {:years => years, :months => months, :days => days}
  end
end

now = Date.today
somewhen =  Date.parse("2010-10-10")

p somewhen.distance_to(now) # => {:years=>0, :months=>6, :days=>29}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def timespan_in_DHMS(time1, time2)
  # returns an array with number of days, hours, minutes and seconds. 
  days, remaining = (time1-time2).to_i.abs.divmod(86400) 
  hours, remaining = remaining.divmod(3600)
  minutes, seconds = remaining.divmod(60)
  [days, hours, minutes, seconds]
end

t1 = Time.new(2000,1,1)
t2 = Time.new(2100,1,1)
p timespan_in_DHMS(Time.now, t1) #=>[4146, 23, 4, 29]
p timespan_in_DHMS(Time.now, t2) #=>[32378, 0, 55, 30]
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the Time class:  [Ruby 1.9](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html), [Ruby 1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Time.html)

> Time is an abstraction of dates and
>   times. Time is stored internally as
>   the number of seconds and microseconds
>   since the epoch, January 1, 1970 00:00
>   UTC.

Comment: Did I somehow misunderstand "nice way to print number of days and hours, minutes?"?

Comment: show some example code instead of just referencing the documentation

Comment: I tend to avoid writing out solutions for someone who hasn't attempted any him/herself.

Answer (score -1):

See [Time#strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000392) from Ruby-doc.